# How to Format datetime_picker in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: activeadmin

I'm currently using ActiveAdmin in a Rails project and trying to format the datetime using datetime_picker.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```rb
f.input :schedule_date_time, 
  label: 'Schedule Date', 
  as: :datetime_picker, 
  datetime_picker_options: { format: 'mm/dd/yyyy H:i' }, 
  input_html: { class: 'datetimepicker' }
```

However, datetime_picker_options seems not to be working, and the datetime format doesn't change to 'mm/dd/yyyy H:i'.

The UI it creates looks like the following:

[image]

Additionally, I have also tried to use jQuery to format the datetime:

```js
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: 'm/d/Y H:i'
});
```

But, this didn't work either.

How can I correctly format the datetime picker to 'mm/dd/yyyy H:i' in ActiveAdmin?